# Ask about jquery function operation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm student and it hasn't been long since I studied programming.
below code is simplified than real for explain.
'test()' is actually Ajax function to get data.
My goal is making 'a tag' for paging operation.
But when i clicked 'a tag', 'test()' inside of '$(document).ready' is called after 'a tag' click event occurred.
So page is always back to 1.
I don't know why this happen.
Anyone could help me?
Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var page = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    test();
    alert(page);
});
function test(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var a = $("<a></a>").text(i).attr({
            href: "",
            idx: i
        });
        a.preventDefault;
        $(a).click(function(){
            page = $(this).attr("idx");
            test();
            alert(page);
        });
        $("#pageLink").append(a," ");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello!
<div id="pageLink"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not part of the problem but `a` is a jQuery object already, you don't need to then wrap it with $().

Comment: I solved problem.
Thank you for advice about jQuery object doesn't need to wrap it with '$()'.
I've not known about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason you're calling test() inside of test(). There are a few minor things you need to change also

- Prefix jQuery objects with $. `var $a=...` to avoid ambiguity.
- [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is used on the event, not the jQuery object. `$a.click(function(event){event.preventDefault();...});`

Otherwise it works as I believe you want it to, alerting the page number on click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    createLinks();
});
function createLinks(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var $a = $("<a></a>").text(i).attr({
            href: "",
            idx: i
        });
       
        $a.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            page = $(this).attr("idx");
            // why are you calling this again? // test();
            // maybe you want to load something // loadSomething(page);
            alert(page);
        });
        $("#pageLink").append($a," ");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello!
<div id="pageLink"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!!
My fault is using 'preventDefault' method to 'a tag' not 'event'.
So  'href="" '  is operated and web page is refreshed and page is back to 1.
I thank you again and have a nice day :)